# Equivalent definitions of rigid transformations

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

My (real) analysis book defines rigid transformations as orthogonal transformations followed by a translation, which I later found out is not the canonical definition of a rigid map. I believe the usual definition is a map $T: X \rightarrow Y$, $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$, st $d_Y(T(x), T(y)) = d_X(x, y)$. According to some authors, $T$ also has to preserve shape (is this an additional condition that is a consequence of distance preservation?).

I've been trying, without much success, to find a proof that, in Euclidean space, all distance-preserving transformations are orthogonal transformations followed by a translation. When I asked someone, he said the only proof he knew involved Riemannian geometry, and he did not know of any more elementary proofs. As someone with a very limited geometry background, I was wondering if anyone knew of one and could enlighten me?

Comment: You can try to compose the map $T$ with a translation $S$ such that $ST(0)=0$ and prove that $ST$ is an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: I learn't a proof from these notes by Keith Conrad:  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/isometryRn.pdf